# How to hook up a 240V 50Hz heat pump to 60Hz

Tags: electrical, heat-pump

I am facing a challenge:
Every EVI (-25C outside) air to water heat pump system seems to be 240V/1Ph/50Hz (and 1 exception I found so far: 240V/1Ph/60Hz, however with extremely limited information, and 1 option is not really an option).

My electrical panel however can deliver me 240V/1Ph/60Hz (30A). So how do I hook up a 50Hz system?

I searched for transformers, but can not seem to find one yet.

What is the best solution to get this heating system hooked up? Any supplier suggestions for transformers?

Thanks

Comment: You should buy the one that's 60 Hz. And hire an electrician to install it, or improve your understanding of your electrical system before proceeding.

Comment: Transformers don't change frequency, you'd be looking for a VFD.

Answer (score 2):

Ask the manufacturer of the desired system how frequency sensitive their system is. Some equipment will work just fine at either 50 or 60 hertz with no adjustment, some will need some minor changes (move jumper or such), some will need major change (replace motors, or add variable frequency drive), some will not work without a rotary phase converter. Do not use a Variable frequency drive on anything other than motors unless endorsed by the manufacturer. Chances are you do not want to mess with a rotary phase converter.

Comment: Given that his issue is the frequency differences I don't see how adding a rotary phase converter would be helpful.

Comment: A rotary phase converter is a electric generator powered by an electric motor. The most common application as you are aware is to convert single phase to three phase (which allows optimization of components by sharing a space) but you can also build a rotary phase converter to do frequency changes but it is complicated by the fact that you can not get a source frequency lock. Possible but a royal pain in the rear to build or find. I have only seen this done once and it was a lab unit.

Answer (score 0):

You would need a VFD aka variable frequency drive.  Here is an [example](http://alexnld.com/product/220v-380v-1-5kw-2-2kw-variable-frequency-drive-vfd-inverter/)

Your load requirements may be different.

Comment: More than likely if you live in a house you have a 240/120 volt split single phase. If this is a commercial establishment you may have 208/120Y.

Comment: To my knowledge, two-phase hasn't been used since the early 1900s.

Comment: Canadian and US are the same - 240V 60Hz center-tapped single phase, wrongly referred to as "2-phase" by folks who don't know better and are perhaps borderline on "should be doing own wiring." A leg is not a phase.

Comment: @Ecnerwal: Thanks, having the right terms helps looking things up on Wikipedia. A youtube video on how to get 240V out of your electrical panel used the incorrect terms, getting me stuck with it.

Comment: @Ecnerwal, just because the phases differ by 180 deg instead of 90 deg.

Answer (score 0):

Your system is really a 120V/240V/1Ph/60Hz system -- simply use the 60Hz heat pump you identified.  (A 50Hz heat pump will likely not work properly on a 60Hz supply.)

Comment: The problem is: There are better systems than the one I found, only they run at 50Hz. The US/Canadian market seems to be locked out of many better performing systems in regards to air to water heat pumps.